# How do I avoid the prompts while using azcopy on Linux in a script?

Tags: linux, azure, azcopy

I've got a Python script that runs the AzCopy command to backup my storage accounts. However, it keeps throwing a prompt with the following message.

> Incomplete operation with different command line detected at the journal directory "/home/azureuser/Microsoft/Azure/AzCopy".
>   Do you want to overwrite the journal to start a new operation? Choose Yes to overwrite, choose No to cancel current operation. (Yes/No) y

On the Windows version of AzCopy I could add the `/Y` parameter. But I'm on a Linux machine.

Is there an equivalent parameter for Linux?

Comment: Could you post some code describing what you've done so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try `azcopy` with the `--quiet` option.

If you type `azcopy --help`, you will see this option with the following description:

```
--quiet              Suppresses all AzCopy confirmation prompts.
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `azcopy sync`, you have to be crafty:

```
echo N | azcopy sync ... --force=false
```